# Trying to remove this in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

This is my first laravel project and i made a simple log in system however i tried to remove this [I want to remove this from my log in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPzrU.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Laravel using view system mechanic to show your html code on your browser, you can edit everything in your `resource/view` folder on your project path. In this case you wanted to remove that headbar register and login button. So find `login.blade.php` on your `resource/view` path folder, and remove the code inside the file. If you use package for that custom login/register, you can find it on `vendor/packagename` folder on your project path.